# Upload all text file content to mongodb (using pymongo)

Tags: file, mongodb, text, upload, pymongo

I'm starting with mongodb.
I have a text file with 3400000 lines of data and I want to upload that data to a mongodb database.

The text file looks like this:

```
360715;157.55.34.97;Mozilla/5.0;/pub/index.asp;NULL
3360714;157.55.32.233;Mozilla/5.0;/pub/index.asp;NULL
....
```

and I want to put it on a mongodb database with the following structure :

```
{'log' : '360715;157.55.34.97;Mozilla/5.0;/pub/index.asp;NULL'}
{'log' : '3360714;157.55.32.233;Mozilla/5.0;/pub/index.asp;NULL'}
....
```

Actually I am uploading line by line like this :

```
for data_line in records:
    parsed_line = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9,.\;():/]', '', data_line) 
    to_insert = unicode(parsed_line, "utf-8")
    db.data_source.insert({'log':to_insert})
```

Is there a way to upload all lines at one time to the format I want to ?
The "line by line" approach is to much slower.

Previously , i had coded a script in python to parse the text file, and it takes one second to 100000 lines and takes 65 seconds to 3400000.

I considered to use mongodb to improve the process but , actually , with mongodb it takes the same time just to upload 100000 lines to the database that my script to performe all the data parse. So is not to much hard to say that I'm doing something badly wrong with mongodb.

I'm grateful if someone can help me.

Greetings , João

Comment: And your question is? Is it what are you doing wrong in MongoDB? I do not see any code that shows what you are doing. So perhaps actually add some so we can tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try bulk inserting the data into mongodb. Right now you are calling insert() once for every single line in your text file which is expensive.

If you are running mongoDB version 2.6.x you can use bulk inserts http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html . Example code below from the tutorial:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> db = pymongo.MongoClient().bulk_example
>>> db.test.insert(({'i': i} for i in xrange(10000)))
[...]
>>> db.test.count()
10000
```

In this case a single insert() call inserted 10000 documents into mongodb.

Another example below:

```
>>> new_posts = [{"author": "Mike",
...               "text": "Another post!",
...               "tags": ["bulk", "insert"],
...               "date": datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 12, 11, 14)},
...              {"author": "Eliot",
...               "title": "MongoDB is fun",
...               "text": "and pretty easy too!",
...               "date": datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 10, 10, 45)}]
>>> posts.insert(new_posts)
[ObjectId('...'), ObjectId('...')]
```

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you John.
I used the second example you gave me and the process became faster.
The construction of the dictionary list takes about 55 seconds and inserting in the database takes 60 seconds. Don´t you think that 120 seconds is to much time ?

Comment: 120 seconds to load into memory 3.4M records and insert them into a mongodb database is close to 30k documents inserted per second. I don't know what hardware you are using or what indexes you have set up on this collection (both of which have a huge impact on insertion speed) but that seems fairly speedy to me.

Comment: For now i'm just using my ultra-book (Intel Core i7-3517UCPU @ 1.9GHz 2.4 GHz | 8GB RAM).
I don't set up anything about the indexes , should i have set up something ? 
Do you know some paper , tutorial or something else that talks about mongoDB optimization ?

Comment: Indexes should depend on how you will query the data - they don't help with insertion. Regarding optimization, besides the free MongoDB classes (which I highly recommend) this is a good place to start: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/optimization/